# Linking a textbox value to coinmill script for currency conversion

Tags: textbox

I got a currency exchange script from coinmill. I want to modify it to work nice in my page. I am a newbie in html/javascript programming thats why i am asking help on this one, pls.

```
<script src="http://coinmill.com/frame.js"></script>
<script>
var currency_round=true;
var currency_decimalSeparator='.';
var currency_thousandsSeparator=',';
var currency_thousandsSeparatorMin=3;
</script>
$199.00 (US) = <script>currency_show_conversion(199.00,"USD","GBP");</script> GBP<br>
<small>Currency data courtesy <a href="http://coinmill.com/">coinmill.com</a></small>
```

This scripts works fine but shows the conversion for the default value in the script. I need to replace the value ($199.00) to a value from a textbox of id "edit_1". Automatically after the user inserts the currency to exchange, the value will show in the page.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Stephen Ostermiller, and I run http://coinmill.com/.  You can make this work with the JavaScript currency API from Coinmill:

- Put on `onchange` event on the textarea
- Get the value from the text area using `this.value`
- use the `currency_convert(value,from,to)` method that is available in `frame.js` to convert it into the currency of your choice
- Write the value to where you want it in the page, for example with `document.getElementById('results').innerHTML`

Putting it all together:

```
<script src="http://coinmill.com/frame.js"></script>
<script>
var currency_round=true;
var currency_decimalSeparator='.';
var currency_thousandsSeparator=',';
var currency_thousandsSeparatorMin=3;
</script>
<textarea id=edit_1 onchange="document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=currency_convert(this.value,'USD','GBP')"></textarea><br>
Converted into GBP:<div id=results></div>
<p><small>Currency data courtesy <a href="http://coinmill.com/">coinmill.com</a></small></p>
```

Whene I enter "273" into the textarea, I then see "Converted into GBP: 176.32" on the page.

You can test out a live example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wAxnq/